# Wordpress the_time formatting

Tags: php, wordpress, time, timestamp

Pretty simple question here, hoping for a simple answer.

I want to display my wordpress time output as DD.MM.YY

So today it would be 10.11.09

I couldn't find anything in the wordpress codex, I supposed its a little php?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
<?php the_time('d.m.y') ?>
```

See the wordpress documentation on [Formatting Date and Time](http://codex.wordpress.org/Formatting_Date_and_Time), and the [PHP documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) for the syntax of the format string.